# Unicode font is displayed as junk even with UTF-8

Tags: migration, encoding, linux

I had a few blogs with unicode content and just migrated them to a new server CentOS - Apache. Now, the unicode fonts are displayed as junk and I am not sure what went wrong.

My wp-config and Apache AddDefaultCharset are set to UTF-8. Still, I see junk.

By the way, the same server serves the Unicode content well in a non-WP page. But, the three WP sites have this issue.

Sample content:
à®…à®´à®•à®¿à®¯ à®¨à®¿à®±à®®à¯à®Ÿà¯ˆà®¯ à®ªà®šà¯à®šà¯ˆà®•à¯à®•à®¿à®³à®¿à®¯à¯‡,

```
My DB details:mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     | 
| character_set_connection | latin1                     | 
| character_set_database   | latin1                     | 
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     | 
| character_set_results    | latin1                     | 
| character_set_server     | latin1                     | 
| character_set_system     | utf8                       | 
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ | 
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please let me know how do I change it so that existing DB content's encoding also gets changed.

Comment: Have you checked the database collation after migration?

Comment: The question is proper but you well have a better chance of getting answers at stack overflow,  migrating

Answer (score 1):

Your data has become misencoded. It's UTF-8 data being interpreted as CP1252.

```
>>> print u'à®…à®´à®•à®¿à®¯ à®¨à®¿à®±à®®'.encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8')
அழகிய நிறம
```

Comment: And the interpretation takes place at? server or db? Please help me understand.

Comment: Use a low-level tool so that you can see the byte sequence actually stored in the database; this will help you to figure out what your next step is.